# Apache multiple rewrite rule

Tags: apache, .htaccess, url-rewriting, xampp

how to rewrite multiple rules in .htaccess file?

The following is my .htaccess:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine On    

    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/download(.*)$
    RewriteRule ^(.*)/download/(.*)$ download/$2 [L]

    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/file(.*)$
    RewriteRule ^(.*)/file/(.*)$ file/$2 [L]

    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ main/$1 [L]
</IfModule>
```

If request url is **http://localhost/{download}/foo.php** then will run download/foo.php

If request url is **http://localhost/{file}/foo/bar.php** then will run file/foo/bar.php

If not in rules then will run main/index.php

Answer (score 1):

Here is example:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine On    

    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/download/.*$ [NC]
    RewriteRule ^/download/(.*) download/$1 [L]

    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/file/.*$ [NC]
    RewriteRule ^/file/(.*) file/$1 [L]


    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^(/download/(.*)|/file/(.*))$ [NC]
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ main/$1 [L]

</IfModule>
```